# Time series package in Mathematica 9

Tags: packages, time-series

Is the time series package already installed in *Mathematica* 9?
I have already installed *Mathematica*.

Do I need to install the time series package?
If so, from where? or should i go for *Mathematica* v10 as per online docs it is pre-installed with time series.m package?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Why not see for yourself by trying to load the package?

Comment: If you mean this [time series](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/timeseries/), then it is third part app, that you need to buy. So it is separate. I did not know about a time series package. Do you have a link?

Comment: Yes. Its the same time series. I dont want to buy the package. Does mathematica v10 already has this time series pre installed. ??

Comment: No, it doesn't have it pre-installed.  It does have time series functionality, but it's probably not compatible with the package you linked to. Please update your question with the link, otherwise it is not clear what you are "referring to by "the time series package"

Comment: As others have pointed out, the only time series package is a third-party package and it is not compatible with Mathematica 9 or later. Mathematica 9 has built-in support for time series via `TemporalData`, and this is greatly expanded on in Mathematica 10.

Comment: I have installed mathematica v10.. i need to run the codes for arma, ma, ar processes. I want to run these code: Needs["TimeSeries'TimeSeries'"]
(to run the time series package), FilePrint[ToFileName["TimeSeries", "Data"<, "file1.dat"]] and many more codes like these. These have been taken from time series documentation file available at wolfrom website. Please help and what should I do run such code for time series evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by Stefan R answers the question.

> As others have pointed out, the only time series package is a third-party package and it is not compatible with *Mathematica* 9 or later. *Mathematica* 9 has built-in support for time series via `TemporalData`, and this is greatly expanded on in *Mathematica* 10.